Angular Standalone Component Routing Error: Not routing properly
So I have been working Angular for a time, but I recently started using v18 only, and wanted to make a simple app with standalone components... I am routing all unidentified path to landing, and from there I have a CTA which would navigate to calculations using router.navigate(url), but it does not... I am facing this issue for days already, tried removing, re-adding parts but still nothing. If I reach the url directly, it works, otherwise it does not... what am I doing wrong? :/
    navigateToNextPhase() {
        this.router.navigate([this.data.continueUrl.url]); -> URL is a string
    }

App.routes.ts
import { Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { environment } from '../environments/environment.prod';

export const appRoutes: Routes = [
    {
        path: 'landing',
        loadComponent: () => import('./pages/landing/landing.component').then((mod) => mod.LandingComponent),
        title: environment.appTitle,
    },
    {
        path: 'calculation',
        loadComponent: () => import('./pages/calculation/calculation.component').then((mod) => mod.CalculationComponent),
        title: environment.appTitle,
    },
    /*{
        path: '',
        redirectTo: '/landing',
        pathMatch: 'full',
    },*/
    {
        path: '**',
        loadComponent: () => import('./pages/error/error.component').then((mod) => mod.ErrorComponent),
        title: environment.appTitle,
    },
];

App.component.ts
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, RouterOutlet } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    standalone: true,
    imports: [CommonModule, RouterOutlet, RouterModule],
    templateUrl: './app.component.html',
    styleUrl: './app.component.scss',
})
export class AppComponent {
    public appTitle: string = 'v18App';
}

Landing.component.ts
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { CardComponent } from '../../components/card/card.component';
import { cardcontent } from '../../models/cardContents';

@Component({
    selector: 'LandingComponent',
    standalone: true,
    imports: [CardComponent],
    templateUrl: './landing.component.html',
    styleUrl: './landing.component.scss',
})
export class LandingComponent {}

Calculation.component.ts
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'CalculationComponent',
    standalone: true,
    imports: [],
    templateUrl: './calculation.component.html',
    styleUrl: './calculation.component.scss',
})
export class CalculationComponent {}

App.config.ts
import { ApplicationConfig, provideExperimentalZonelessChangeDetection } from '@angular/core';
import { provideRouter } from '@angular/router';
import { appRoutes } from './app.routes';
import { provideClientHydration, provideProtractorTestingSupport } from '@angular/platform-browser';

export const appConfig: ApplicationConfig = {
    providers: [
        provideProtractorTestingSupport(),
        provideExperimentalZonelessChangeDetection(),
        provideRouter(appRoutes),
        provideClientHydration(),
    ],
};


where is navigateToNextPhase called, what is the url navigation, if possible a working stackblitz example

Inside Landing component I use a standalone component, Card.component.ts, inside it I call the method.

what is the url used, please share the string value, could you please share the respective HTML also, mainly, router-outlet part alone

@NarenMurali the string value is calculation. The representetive part is below:
            <span>{{data.cardContent.contentMain}}</span>
            <button class="button button--primary button--cta" title="Start" (click)="navigateToNextPhase()">Start</button>
        </form>```

Since you are navigating to the root path (/) you should go for absolute routing, which always checks from the root element, so calculation will be discoverable.
navigateToNextPhase() {
    this.router.navigate(['/calculation']); // -> absolute routing
}

The issue might be when set calculation, it is checking for calculation route relative to the landing component.

I would say it can solve the issue, but unfortunately not. It remains the same... however if I uncomment the wildcard error component in routing, it immediately routes me there instead of actually using the string I send through, despite the string is there even in the moment of clicking the cta...
